# Is there a succinct way of adding values to a data frame based on other values?

Tags: r

I have a list of retailer codes.

I wish to add the retailer name/country to the `retailer` column based on the retailer code so that humans looking at the results will be able to understand which retailer they relate to.

At present, I have this:

```
chats$retailer[chats$retailer_code == "npqPjZyMy5"] <- "France"
chats$retailer[chats$retailer_code == "HbNaIqdedB"] <- "Germany"
chats$retailer[chats$retailer_code == "p7VtqCMCr8"] <- "Italy"
chats$retailer[chats$retailer_code == "Tj8vwJvyH1"] <- "Japan"
chats$retailer[chats$retailer_code == "1mRdYODJBH"] <- "UAE"
chats$retailer[chats$retailer_code == "GGdwO3HFDV"] <- "UK"

chats$retailer_code <- NULL # Remove retailer code column
```

Is there a more succinct way to achieve this?

Comment: Check out dplyr::case_when

Comment: Or `base::switch`.

Comment: Also, if your key-value map gets really big, just store this as its own table, then do a table join (e.g. `base::merge`, `dplyr::left_join` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This will save some of your time .

```
library(plyr)
chats$retailer <- revalue(chats$retailer,
                                  c("npqPjZyMy5" = "France", "HbNaIqdedB" = "Germany", "p7VtqCMCr8" = "Italy", "Tj8vwJvyH1" = "Japan","1mRdYODJBH" = "UAE","GGdwO3HFDV" = "UK" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
chats%>%
  mutate(retailer = case_when(
    retailer_code=="npqPjZyMy5"~"France",
    retailer_code=="HbNaIqdedB"~"Germany",
    retailer_code=="p7VtqCMCr8"~"Italy",
    retailer_code=="Tj8vwJvyH1"~"Japan",
    retailer_code=="1mRdYODJBH"~"UAE",
    retailer_code=="GGdwO3HFDV"~"UK"))%>%
  select(-retailer_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with a lookup vector:

```
# data
set.seed(123)
codes <- c("npqPjZyMy5", "HbNaIqdedB", "p7VtqCMCr8", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "1mRdYODJBH", "GGdwO3HFDV")
ctrys <- c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "Japan", "UAE", "UK")
chats <- data.frame(retailer_code = sample(codes, 20, replace = T),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# solution
ctrys_lookup <- setNames(ctrys, codes)
chats$retailer <- ctrys_lookup[chats$retailer_code]
chats
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in a base R solution for good measure.

```
# Example data
chats <- data.frame(
  other_column = 1:6,
  retailer_code = c("npqPjZyMy5", "HbNaIqdedB", "p7VtqCMCr8", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "1mRdYODJBH", "GGdwO3HFDV")
)

# Example key
retailer_key <- data.frame(
  retailer_code = c("npqPjZyMy5", "HbNaIqdedB", "p7VtqCMCr8", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "1mRdYODJBH", "GGdwO3HFDV"),
  retailer = c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "Japan", "UAE", "UK")
)

# Example join using base::merge
merge(chats, retailer_key)
```